# Auth Routes in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm beginner in Laravel 8. I want users not to go to the 'login' and 'register' routes when they are logged in. I'm using jetstream but I'm not using the routes and views that jetstream have view/routes. I tried but couldn't find the solution. How can I do that?

**My route is:**

```
Route::get('/register', [HomeController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
Route::get('/login', [HomeController::class, 'login_page'])->name('login');
```

**My controller is:**

```
    public function register(){
        return view('design2.registerpage');

        
    }

    public function login_page(){
        return view('design2.loginpage');
    }
```

Comment: As a beginner of Laravel framework, you shouldn't use Jetstream starter kit rather try breeze or laravel/ui starter kits

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#registering-middleware)

It allows you to intercept a request, check if the user is logged in and redirect if he is.

Comment: sorry. i added now

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `guest` middleware

```
Route::get('/register', [HomeController::class, 'register'])->name('register')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/login', [HomeController::class, 'login_page'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel UI Auth All Routes:**

```
    // Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');

// Confirm Password (added in v6.2)
Route::get('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm')->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm');

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify'); // v6.x
/* Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify'); // v5.x */
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```